# Finding the pivot for the eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Below is an example in my lecture notes for finding the eigenvectors. In particular, this one is for the eigenvalue 2. I forgot why $v_1 = s \in R$ and $v_3 = t \in R$. Could it equally have been $v_2 = t \in R$ in which we have $v_3=0.5t$? I'm not sure whether my note saying "other possible solutions exist" means scalar multiples or the case where $v_3=0.5t$. I even looked at my lecture recordings and she said $r_2$ is the "pivot". Can someone please clear this up for me. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question should have no comments like "don't post pictures" by users who don't understand the context which is the current trend. There's no possible way to actually explain what the "lecture" notes say in words instead of pictures. The op has written the main body of the question in words

Comment: Your teacher should not have really used $s$ and $t$ again for $v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$ which are variables themselves. You see that after your teacher brings the matrix to it's echelon form, if you read off the first row, you get $v_{2}-2v_{3}=0$. Hence $(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})=(v_{1},2v_{3},v_{3})=v_{1}(1,0,0)+v_{3}(0,2,1)$ Hence both $(1,0,0)$ (and all it's scalar multiples) and $(0,2,1)$ are eigen vectors (and so are all it's scalar multiples).

Comment: The condition that any eigenvector is of the form $\{v_{1}(1,0,0)+v_{3}(0,2,1):v_{1},v_{2}\in\Bbb{R}\}$ means that your eigenspace is the span of $\{(1,0,0),(0,2,1)\}$ and since $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,2,1)$ are linearly independent, they for a basis for your eigenspace corresponding to eigen value $2$. So by other possible solutions, you teacher means any other basis for the $2$ dimensional space spanned by $\{(1,0,0),(0,2,1)\}$.